# What does this expression do? Gui % (MainGui:=!MainGui) ? "Hide" : "Show"

Tags: if-statement, timer, autohotkey

I find this code on this thread: [Suspending, Pausing, Hiding, Pulling Up GUI Window](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/124512-suspending-pausing-hiding-pulling-up-gui-window/):

```
Gui % (MainGui:=!MainGui) ? "Hide" : "Show"
```

What does it do? I guess it's a kind of a simple [`if` expression](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/IfExpression.htm) for [hotkeys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm), but checking the examples on the two pages I don't see where it locates.

If `SetTimer` is used, the counter will only increase if that code is put inside the subroutine. If put outside, the counter stops.

```
Gui +LastFound +AlwaysOnTop +ToolWindow -Caption
Gui, Add, Text, vcounter, 00000
Gui, Show, NoActivate 

SetTimer, Update, 100 ; 100 ms
Update:
    counter++
    GuiControl,, counter, %counter%
    ^esc::Gui % (MainGui:=!MainGui) ? "Hide" : "Show"
Return
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a kind of [operator in expressions](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm#Operators):

> **Ternary operator** [v1.0.46+]. This operator is a shorthand replacement
>   for the if-else statement. It evaluates the condition on its left side
>   to determine which of its two branches should become its final result.
>   For example, var := x>y ? 2 : 3 stores 2 in Var if x is greater than
>   y; otherwise it stores 3. To enhance performance, only the winning
>   branch is evaluated (see short-circuit evaluation).

The command `^esc::Gui % (MainGui:=!MainGui) ? "Hide" : "Show"` has two parts.

1. `(MainGui:=!MainGui)` Switches the value of the variable `MainGui`
   to it's oposite, usually from `True` to `False` and vice versa.
2. Uses the standard form of the ternary operator to check the value of
   the variable `MainGui`. If it is `True` it uses the value `Hide`,
       if it is `False` it uses the value `Show`.

`^esc::Gui % (MainGui:=!MainGui) ? "Hide" : "Show"` translates to one of the following  after all evaluations:
1. If `MainGui` is `True`  ==>  `Gui Hide`
2. If `MainGui` is `False`  ==>  `Gui Show`

Short explanation: The `^esc` hotkey hides the Gui if it is active, shows it if it is hidden.

Comment: I see. Do you know why the counter stops if it is put outside SetTimer?

Comment: You should put it **after** the SetTimer, not before.

Comment: I know. But why is it?

Comment: After the definition of the `^esc` hotkey the [Auto-execute Section](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Scripts.htm#auto)  ends. Any code after that can only be called via a hotkey, timer or OnMessage() function.